# What is the runtime complexity of 'advance()' when when used for std::set in c++?

Tags: c++, stl

I am curious about the runtime complexity of `std::advance()` when used for `std::set`.

eg.

```
std::set<in> s;
auto x=s.begin();
advance(x,n/2);
```

how much time (order of n) does the above code take.

Answer (score 7):

`std::set` has bidirectional iterators. Bidirectional iterators are incrementable and decrementable, but not random access addressable -- meaning that to reach the `N`nth node requires incrementing `N` times.

This means that advancing by N will be O(N)

Comment: This is correct if advancing the iterator is O(1), is there such a guarantee?

Comment: Relevant question: [iterator++ complexity for stl map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22013987/580083).

Comment: @Dani the standard is clear that complexity is linear. It is vague in what operations are being analysed. But it is reasonable to assume that it is number of calls to ++

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) over at cppreference:

> **Complexity**
>
> Linear.
>
> However, if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of
> LegacyRandomAccessIterator, complexity is constant.

So unless you have a LegacyRandomAccessIterator on your hands (like the one of, say `int[100]`) you have linear complexity. A [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) however, has "only" a LegacyBidirectionalIterator, which is weaker than random access.

So, you here, you are guaranteed to have linear runtime.